# Send post-variable with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to send post-variables with javascript?
I want `id` to be sent with post, not get.

```
window.location.href="hanteraTaBortAnvandare.php?id=10";
```

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is to just have a form in your page:

```
<form method="POST" action="hanteraTaBortAnvandare.php" id="DeleteUserForm">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" />
</form>
```

Then you just post the form:

```
document.getElementById("DeleteUserForm").submit();
```

Comment: Yes, but before sending the form, I want `alert()` the user to conform (yes or no) sending the form.

Comment: That's easy, just use a confirmation in an if statement: if (window.confirm('Vill du verkligen radera användaren?')) { post form... }

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a form and then `document.getElementById('id_of_the_form').submit();`

The form doesn't need to be wrote as plain HTML: you can create it dinamically:

```
     function postIt()   {
        form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        form.setAttribute('action', 'someURL');
        myvar = document.createElement('input');
        myvar.setAttribute('name', 'somename');
        myvar.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        myvar.setAttribute('value', 'somevalue');
        form.appendChild(myvar);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();   
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with an Ajax-request (or use hidden forms) - in that case;

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/) example:

```
new Request({
    url: 'hanteraTaBortAnvandare.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        'id': '10'
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'hanteraTaBortAnvandare.php',
    data: 'id=10',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Of course you could do this without external libraries, but they simplify alot!

Comment: +1 for code examples.  You might consider including a link to MooTools.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit form data via JavaScript but not using window.location.href.  Changing the URL location is always going to issue a GET.

You'll need to get a reference to your form from the DOM and then issue a submit() call to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**XMLHTTPRequest() object.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Please do not provide "w3fools" (please google it) references, their closed (non wiki type) form doesn't provide quality knowledge.

Comment: Alternative link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest