# Trying to submit a javascript variable as a placeholder value with no user input. Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

There are four inputs in my form; token_name, token_expire_date, token_issue_date, token_value. The first two require user input however the second two do not (token_issue_date, token_value). These fields are are predetermined however i need them all to end up in the same mongodb document. Here is my pages/index.js file.

```
import {FieldValues, useForm, UseFormRegister} from "react-hook-form";
import {ToastContainer, toast} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const Loading = () => <div>Loading...</div>;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

async function saveFormData(data, url) {
    return await fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        method: "POST"
    })
}

const Index = () => {
  
    const issuedDate = new Date();
    const selectedKey = "123abc";
    const tokenPlaceholder = selectedKey;
    const fields = [
        {type: "text", name: "token_name", required: true, label: "token_name"},
        {type: "date", name: "token_expire_date", required: true, label: "token_expire_date"},
        {type: "text", name: "token_issue_date", required: true, label: "token_issue_date", placeholder: issuedDate},
        {type: "text", name: "token_value", required: true, label: "token_value", placeholder: tokenPlaceholder}
    ]

    const renderForm = ({register, errors, isSubmitting}) => {
        return <>
            {fields.map(field => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <label htmlFor={field.name}>{field.label}</label>
                        <input type={field.type} autoComplete={field.autoComplete} placeholder={field.placeholder}
                                {...register(field.name, {required: field.required})} />
                        <div className="error">{errors[field.name]?.message}</div>
                    </>
                )
            })}

            <button disabled={isSubmitting}>
                {isSubmitting ? <Loading/> : "Submit"}
            </button>
        </>;
    }
    return <FormComponent url="/api/form" renderForm={renderForm} />
    }

function FormComponent({url, renderForm}) {
  const {data, error} = useSWR(url, fetcher)
  const {register, reset, handleSubmit, setError, formState: {isSubmitting, errors, isDirty}} = useForm();

  useConfirmRedirectIfDirty(isDirty)

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
      const response = await saveFormData(data, url)

      if (response.status === 400) {
          // Validation error, expect response to be a JSON response {"field": "error message for that field"}
          const fieldToErrorMessage = await response.json()
          for (const [fieldName, errorMessage] of Object.entries(fieldToErrorMessage)) {
              setError(fieldName, {type: 'custom', message: errorMessage})
          }
      } else if (response.ok) {
          // successful
          toast.success("Successfully saved")
      } else {
          // unknown error
          toast.error("An unexpected error occurred while saving, please try again")
      }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return; // loading
      }
      reset(data);
  }, [reset, data]);

  if (error) {
      return <div>An unexpected error occurred while loading, please try again</div>
  } else if (!data) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

 
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {renderForm({register, errors, isSubmitting})}
      <ToastContainer position="bottom-center"/>
  </form>;
}
```

I am able to get the variables to render as placeholders but i am not able to get them to submit to my database as placeholders... It doesn't seem to work without the user typing anything in. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey y'all I was able to answer my question from earlier with the help of this other Stackoverflow post... [Send post-variable with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350917/send-post-variable-with-javascript)

Just add the HTML input hidden attribute with

type: "hidden"

Thanks @Guffa